# Cordova InAppBrowser close button like Sworkit App

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I want to add a close button to InAppBrowser like the one in the sworkit app.

[image]

Comment: the close button shown in above image is not of sworkit app. It's part of facebook sdk. and it's same in every app where facebook sdk is used as means to authenticate user.

Comment: @Yogesh It is also coming when user try to authenticate with google... they made some changes in plugin... it will be helpful someone tell me what are those and how to do that

Answer (score 0):

As a Sworkit developer, I can confirm that this is not being done directly with Cordova's InAppBrowser by us. This is what is supplied by Firebase for `Firebase.authWithOAuthPopup()`

https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/authwithoauthpopup.html

Here is what Firebase has to say about it..

*To use the InAppBrowser plugin, do absolutely nothing. Yep, by simply installing the plugin, everything is handled for you.*

*The problem is, that on mobile there is no analogous “popup” view. The authWithOAuthPopup() method uses window.open() to to open up a new popup window. When this happens, Cordova won’t know what to do.*

*The InAppBrowser plugin fixes this by showing a web browser in your app when window.open() is called.*

https://www.firebase.com/blog/2016-01-14-firebase-ionic-social-login.html

Comment: Hi Ryan,

Thanks for your reply. 
I am having issue on adding **phonegap-facebook-plugin** with **cordova.plugin.local-notification**. Please help me.

Comment: What exactly is happening there? Want to open up another question for that?